# App to organize my photos into folders by date

Tags: macos, applications

Is there an app on OS X that can sort through all your photos within a folder and organize them into folders and name each folder the date it was taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bash script that sorts files into `year/month/day/` directory paths.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
dir="$1"
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | while IFS= read -r file; do
  year=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%y" $file)
  month=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%m" $file)
  day=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%d" $file)
  mkdir -p "$dir/$year/$month/$day"
  mv "$file" "$dir/$year/$month/$day"
done
```

**Untested**, have backups, etc.; if you are unfamiliar with shell scripts I wouldn't recommend this hacked-together, untested script that I wrote late at night be the very first script you run!

Save the script (e.g. `file.sh`), then run

```
chmod u+x /path/to/file.sh && /path/to/file.sh /path/to/directory
```

Comment: This is using the filesystem timestamp - depending on the files, might be worth checking the EXIF data (if it's available) using something like ExifTool. You could have the script check Exif and use that, then fall back to the filesystem data, or log differences.

Answer (score 0):

Aperture can import images and have them sorted by date but you end up with projects inside Aperture (the project names are the dates the photos were taken). Make sure the Preferences » Import settings are set to split import into "One Project Per Day". If you don't want to keep them in Aperture, you can easily export them back out into folders.